# React callback not getting updated before navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm sure this is a situation which can be fixed by `async/await`, but I can't see where that should be applied.

I have three components.  One component is a timer which receives a callback from the parent and returns the remaining time left when the timer is stopped.  The parent component receives this data and navigates to a results page.  However, navigation happens before the data is received so isn't passed.  If you navigate back and repeat the process, the *previous* data is then shown so I know it works in theory, but it's just a case of waiting for the data to arrive.

*timer component*

```
export const Timer = ({ seconds, timerRunning, checkForTimeLimit }) => {
  const [timeLimit, settimeLimit] = React.useState(seconds);
  const [timerActive, setTimerActive] = React.useState(timerRunning);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimerActive(timerRunning);
    settimeLimit(seconds);
    return function cleanup() {
      setTimerActive(false);
    }
  }, [timerRunning]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLimit > 0 && timerActive) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        settimeLimit(timeLimit - 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (timeLimit === 0 && timerRunning || !timerRunning) {
      checkForTimeLimit(timeLimit); // When the timer is stopped, it passes back the remaining time
    }
  }, [timeLimit, timerActive]);

 //...Other stuff
```

*parent component*

```
export const Test = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = React.useState(timerIsRunning);
  const [secondsForTest, setSecondsForTest] = React.useState(minutes * 60);
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = React.useState(0);

  const handleCheckForTimeLimit = (timeLimit) => {
    setRemainingTime(timeLimit); // Receives the remaining time from timer and sets to state
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 10 }}>
      {timed ? (
        <Timer
          seconds={secondsForTest}
          timerRunning={timerRunning}
          checkForTimeLimit={(
            timeLimit // passes callback to timer
          ) => handleCheckForTimeLimit(timeLimit)}
        />
      ) : null}

      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          setTimerRunning(false); // stops timer and triggers callback
          setResponseDetails({ answered: false, index: null });
          setActiveIndex(0);
          setStoredResponses([]);
          navigation.navigate('Results', {
            // navigates to results page and passes in data
            data: storedResponses,
            category: category,
            timed: timed,
            minutes: minutes,
            remainingTime: remainingTime,
          });
        }}
        disabled={!responseDetails.answered}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text>Results</Text>
        <Icon name="arrow-dropright" />
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

*results page*

```
export const Results = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { category, data: testData, timed, minutes, remainingTime } = route.params;
  // remainingTime is not populated
}
```

How should I update this code so that `remainingTime` is populated and passed to the results page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your callback is used to set `timeLimit`, navigation should be an effect of change applied to `timeLimit` (navigation should not be in the press handler).

So just wrap your navigation in `useCallback` and pass it as dependency to the effect which triggers on `timeLimit` change.

**UPDATE**

Try to use additional state to allow navigation only when the button is pressed.

```
export const Test = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = React.useState(timerIsRunning);
  const [secondsForTest, setSecondsForTest] = React.useState(minutes * 60);
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = React.useState(0);

  // use additional state
  const [isNavigationAllowed, setIsNavigationAllowed] = React.useState(false);

  const handleCheckForTimeLimit = (timeLimit) => {
    setRemainingTime(timeLimit); // Receives the remaining time from timer and sets to state
  };

  // move navigation into callback
  const navigateToResult = useCallback(() => {
    navigation.navigate("Results", {
      data: storedResponses,
      category: category,
      timed: timed,
      minutes: minutes,
      remainingTime: remainingTime,
    });
  }, [storedResponses, category, timed, minutes, remainingTime]);

  // navigate only when you allow it
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isNavigationAllowed) {
      navigateToResult();
    }
  }, [navigateToResult, isNavigationAllowed]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 10 }}>
      {timed ? (
        <Timer
          seconds={secondsForTest}
          timerRunning={timerRunning}
          checkForTimeLimit={(
            timeLimit // passes callback to timer
          ) => handleCheckForTimeLimit(timeLimit)}
        />
      ) : null}

      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          setTimerRunning(false); // stops timer and triggers callback
          setResponseDetails({ answered: false, index: null });
          setActiveIndex(0);
          setStoredResponses([]);
          // allow navigation only after button is pressed
          setIsNavigationAllowed(true);
        }}
        disabled={!responseDetails.answered}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text>Results</Text>
        <Icon name="arrow-dropright" />
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I understand the theory behind this and it makes sense, but when I've tried doing it this way it results in `navigateToResult()` firing immediately on page load as `timeLimit`/`remainingTime` are both updated straight away. Any thoughts on a way around that?

Comment: @Sternjobname updated the answer. Try to use additional flag state and trigger effect by changing that particular flag state

Comment: Got it! Had to make a couple of tweaks to get it all working, but thank you for putting me on the right path - that was definitely easier than I was expecting!